# Activation Lock Ipod 5

Tags: ipod-touch, ios, activation-lock

I have a iPod 5 touch with the iOs 7.0.4 and I can't get through the Activation Lock and I have no contact with the Apple ID owner. Is there any bypass for this? **Please Help**

Answer (score 3):

In theory, the answer is **no**. Activation Lock is designed to make bypassing it impossible.

However, [this page](http://www.doulci.net) claims to be able to bypass activation lock using some questionable mojo. Use at your own risk.

Alternatively, take the device to Apple with proof that you legitimately purchased it, and they should either be able to unlock it for you, or help you get in contact with the person who owns the account to which the device is locked.