# iPhone 4 requires previous Apple ID

Tags: iphone, activation-lock

I bought a used iPhone 4, got the carrier to unlock to use, but I still can't use because I don't have the previous owner's Apple ID or password. Is there any way to unlock to use?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, but you cannot use your iPhone without entering the code correctly. You may want to refer to this question here, as suggested by tubedogg: [Activation Lock Ipod 5](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/155589/activation-lock-ipod-5)